# Java: updated class files not used

Tags: java, python

I'm developing a Java program through Eclipse locally, and debugging on a remote machine. Whenever I make a change to my program, I copy the corresponding class file to the bin directory on the remote machine.  I run my program (a simulator) through a python script via the OS.system command.

The problem is that my program *sometimes* does not use the updated class files after they have been moved over.

The problem persists even if I log out and back into the remote machine. What's really strange is that, as a test, I deleted the bin directory entirely on the remote machine, and was still able to run my program.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: are you starting and stopping the JVM in the remote machine ? ie it is fresh each time?

Comment: I believe so. Either the script executes entirely (at the end of which I assume the JVM exits), or I terminate execution with CTRL+C.

Comment: "believe", "assume"... yeah, I'd start there.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity - my experience is limited when it comes to the JVM. I'm not doing anything explicit to start or stop the JVM (is this different from starting and stopping the Java program?). In my script, I simply use OS.system to start my Java program, and then either let it run to completion, or I stop the script with CTRL+C.

Answer (score 1):

I would bet dollars for donuts that under some conditions you are not restarting the JVM between tests.

The other obvious thought is that the class is not being copied to the target system as expected, or not to the correct location.  Or, of course, the program is not being run from where you expect (i.e. there is another copy of the class files, perhaps in a JAR, which is actually be run).

Explicitly recheck *all* your assumptions.

Comment: Other than breaking execution of the program or letting it run to completion, is there a way to stop the JVM explicitly?  Also, is there a way to check if the JVM is still running?  (When I type 'ps' into the terminal, it does not indicate that a Java process is running.) To clarify, I never copy the class files while the simulator is active (to the best of my knowledge.)